# Manage several chat button ids

Tags: javascript, liveagent

This is my code in html template:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://url.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/40.0/deployment.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (!window._laq) {
        window._laq = [];
    }
    window._laq.push(function(){
        liveagent.showWhenOnline('5730Y000000g549', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_5730Y000000g549'));
        liveagent.showWhenOffline('5730Y000000g549', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_5730Y000000g549'));
    });
</script>

<!-- START chat Button code -->
<button class="chat" id="liveagent_button_online_5730Y000000g549" href="javascript://Chat" style="display: none;" onclick="liveagent.startChat('5730Y000000g549')">
    <img src="favicon.ico">
</button>
<!-- END chat Button code -->
```

In my controller:

```
vm.initChatPage = function() {
    SalesforceService.initPage();
};

vm.initChatPage();
```

And in my SalesforceService:

```
initPage() {
    liveagent.init('https://url.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '5720Y000000g5XS', '00D0Y000001l0UT');
}
```

What I want to do is to add a service that does something like:

```
if (language = us) 
     chat button id = 5730Y000000g549
else 
     chat button id = 5730Y333300g540
```

I tried several methods but everytime I got problems like errors that ask wait until the `liveagent.init()` finishes et it never works. Do you have any idea how I can manage several button ids?